# find the number of continious function?

Tags: real-analysis

how many  number of continious function on R which satisfy $ [f(x)]^2 =x^2$  for all $x\in R$ ?

1) 2

2) 4

3) 1

4)  6

i think answer will be option 1   becoz  $x^2= 1$ has two solution

Comment: Certainly $x$ and $-x$ are solutions... have you considered others such, as $|x|$ (that is, a combination of the previous two)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four solutions.

1) y=x

2) y=-x

3) y=|x|

4) y= -|x|

Notice that these are continuous functions and they are different.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.